# Will a second GPU allow me to address more screens in 4K?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, dual-gpu

I'm currently planning a setup with 5 screens (3 HDMI TVs, 2 DP Monitors), all of them 4K. For work, by the way, not gaming. Because some of the software I use restricts the number of permitted sessions to 1, I will actually have to connect all those screens to one single PC.

My GPU (RX Vega 64 with 8GB RAM) comes with 3 DP and 1 HDMI outputs. Clearly, that's not enough. Plus, I will have to add least 2 DP to HDMI adapters for the TVs.

I never worked with so many screens before so I'm really not sure how to set this up without losing quality. I understand it's possible to buy a splitter that will simply create more HDMI or DP ports.

This bears the question, can I address this many 4K screens from the one card?

If not, will a second card increase the total available resolution for the system?

Comment: Few regular consumer cards can actually run all 4 outputs. Maybe three, but very often one DP & the HDMI will be ganged from one actual output. Second consideration is that your CPU will have to drive all those screens too. The GPU can only draw what the CPU tells it. Unless you have serious cooling you're going to struggle. 5x4K screens is quite a heavy lift.

Comment: The [Radeon RX VEGA 64 GAMING OC Graphics Card](https://www.gigabyte.com/my/Press/News/1585) is said to support 6 terminals, although this isn't exactly your model. This is corroborated by Wikipedia [AMD Eyefinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Eyefinity). I suppose you could try to daisy-chain two monitors off one DP port (needs the right monitors).

Comment: I have 2 Eizo EV 3285. They should support Daisy Chaining but I couldn't find any info on resolution. An older model would not support 4K with chaining.

Comment: And thanks for the Eyefinity link. That does seem helpful. I'm just a bit confused about the row max resolution. With older cards, it says "2-6" outputs, with Vega it says 3, at a higher resolution, though.